# constructor injection for Dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, constructor-injection

When we call an api with browser, it reaches to a correspondent controller and resolve all dependency having on constructor. 
My question is who invoke unitycontainer resolve method?

I am using Microsoft.Practice.unity for implementation.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your constructor and follow the call stack.

Comment: Probably Unity's [UnityDependencyResolver](https://github.com/unitycontainer/aspnet-mvc/blob/master/src/UnityDependencyResolver.cs#L33).

Comment: but how unityDependencyResolver would be able to call if I want to make such functionality, how would i acheive that?

Comment: Thanks for your generous answers to a newbie like me. I searched and found dependency resolution invoke is part of application execution pipeline, that we attach at application start.